# ¿Cómo optimizar consulta Linq To Sql con Group By para obtener sumatoria?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Tengo esta consulta donde obtengo un grupo  de registros, pero necesito obtener un SUM por cada  Familia existente.

Ahora utilizo este código pero creo que puedo optimizarlo, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

```
var registros = (from dCabecera in db.A_DocumentoCabecera
                                     join dlFactura in db.A_DocumentoLineaFactura on dCabecera.IdCabecera equals dlFactura.IdCabecera
                                     join articulo  in db.A_Articulo on dlFactura.IdArticulo equals articulo.IdArticulo
                                     join aFamilia in db.A_ArticuloFamilia on articulo.IdFamiliaArticulo equals aFamilia.IdFamiliaArticulo
                                     join empresa in db.A_Empresa on dCabecera.IdEmpresa equals empresa.IdEmpresa
                                     where dCabecera.FechaCrea >= fechaInicial && dCabecera.FechaCrea <= fechaFinal && dCabecera.IdEmpresa == usuario.IdEmpresa
                                     select new { dCabecera, dlFactura,articulo,aFamilia, empresa }).AsEnumerable()
                                     .Select(x => new DashClienteDataPie
                                     {
                                         Familia = x.aFamilia.NombreFamilia,
                                         Importe = x.dlFactura.ImporteTotalBI

                                     }).ToList();

            var lst = new List<DashClienteDataPie>();
            var single = new DashClienteDataPie();
            var familia = new List<string>();
            foreach (var x in registros)
            {
                if (!familia.Contains(x.Familia))
                {
                    familia.Add(x.Familia);
                    single.Familia= x.Familia;
                    single.Importe = registros.Where(i => i.Familia == x.Familia).Sum(i => i.Importe);
                    lst.Add(single);
                    single = new DashClienteDataPie();
                }
            }

            return lst;
```

Comment: Hola, como tal cual es el objetivo de tu consulta?, y otra pregunta, una familia puede tener varios importes?

Comment: El objetivo es hacer un Sum de cada familia  y por supuesto  existen varias filas de datos  y entre ellas diferentes familias e importes

Comment: No me entendiste, lo que te pregunté es cuantos importes puede tener una misma familia